# How to pass json via a form element

Tags: jquery, django, json, flash

I have this swf (flash) file that provides the json that needs to be sent to the server.

I wrote a very simple jQuery:

```
function submitForm(swf_json) {
$('#swfjson').val(swf_json); #swfjson is an input of type hidden
$('#titleForm').submit();
}
```

and the swf will call the submitForm above and I receive the request.POST in django as usual.

But, django is interpreting the `swf_json` as a string `"Object object"`

```
    >>>type(request.POST['swfjson'])
    <type 'unicode'>
```

Of course I can pass the json as a string to the view function. Doesn't seem good to me. Any other way of passing the json object to the django view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course django sees the string "Object object". That's excatly what jQuery writes into the input field. And what subsequently gets submitted. ([Demo](http://jsbin.com/imusu))

The `swf_json` parameter is an object to javascript. If you want to submit it as string I suggest slightly modifying the swf so that it passes a string to your function instead of an json object. Assuming you construct your json via string concatenation just add extra quotation marks at the end and beginning before calling `submitForm`

Instead of

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith"
} //json object
```

try this

```
'{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith"
}' //string
```

---

If I remember correctly https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js allows conversion between json and strings

Comment: Thanks, Thats what I thought. Simple to just pass the string around. But I receive a json from the swf, how do I in the javascript convert it into a string.

Comment: check expanded answer (at end)

Answer (score 3):

You must first "serialize" your *JavaScript object* into a *JSON string* using a library such as https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js (there is no appropriate function built into JQuery.)

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery function [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post("your/url/", 
       {"id":id}, 
       function(data){},
       "json");
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem since it will still send a json object.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to jitter's answer, why not simply parse the json object using Python's [json library](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html). This way you don't need to parse through the string manually. As an added bonus it's more future-proof in case your client decides to pass more than one value through the json object.

Comment: setting an input value and submitting that form is simpler than using an ajax post. This way impedes my development as I cant create a json object in a python test.